# How to use watch function to watch event in contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-debugging

This is my contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Coin{
  address public minter;
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;

  event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

  function Coin(){
    minter = msg.sender;
  }

  function mint(address receiver, uint amount){
    if(msg.sender != minter) return;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
  }

  function send(address receiver, uint amount){
    if(balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    Sent(msg.sender,receiver,amount);
  }

  function balances(address _account) constant returns (uint){
    return balances[_account];
  }
}
```

I deployed it and it's work.

But when I tried to use this.

```
coin.Sent().watch({}, '', function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("Coin transfer: " + result.args.amount +
            " coins were sent from " + result.args.from +
            " to " + result.args.to + ".");
        console.log("Balances now:\n" +
            "Sender: " + Coin.balances.call(result.args.from) +
            "Receiver: " + Coin.balances.call(result.args.to));
    }
})
```

It's return.

```
{
  callbacks: [{}],
  filterId: "0x2d3292bad45ae1726298daea69f0a9ca",
  getLogsCallbacks: [],
  implementation: {
    getLogs: function(),
    newFilter: function(),
    poll: function(),
    uninstallFilter: function()
  },
  options: {
    address: "0x98d83856f246094f992cd46d63ed7d59add9af1c",
    from: undefined,
    fromBlock: undefined,
    to: undefined,
    toBlock: undefined,
    topics: ["0x3990db2d31862302a685e8086b5755072a6e2b5b780af1ee81ece35ee3cd3345"]
  },
  pollFilters: [],
  requestManager: {
    polls: {
      0x1a0d1329ef0ce775db9825ef20e46a3e: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x1a0d1329ef0ce775db9825ef20e46a3e",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0x2d3292bad45ae1726298daea69f0a9ca: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x2d3292bad45ae1726298daea69f0a9ca",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0x3099225b975a0797ff542da6be20f607: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x3099225b975a0797ff542da6be20f607",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0x44637ee54b3f71957baad8ca9186eba7: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x44637ee54b3f71957baad8ca9186eba7",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0x61c0d2e6e4e0a36a21b480a668d719f7: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x61c0d2e6e4e0a36a21b480a668d719f7",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0x8fea259ff20639daabb6567cbbb76d30: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x8fea259ff20639daabb6567cbbb76d30",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0x9b34a52d49ff3929686838a7fa2fbb4b: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x9b34a52d49ff3929686838a7fa2fbb4b",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0xaaff5bc5574bb101cc2f4c110a595c69: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0xaaff5bc5574bb101cc2f4c110a595c69",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0xbeb7e9b0ee8a2db56b1735166820e9aa: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0xbeb7e9b0ee8a2db56b1735166820e9aa",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      },
      0xfb667d7e00183671bb05c0e0653a31c3: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0xfb667d7e00183671bb05c0e0653a31c3",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      }
    },
    provider: {
      newAccount: function(),
      send: function github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console.(*bridge).Send-fm(),
      sendAsync: function github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console.(*bridge).Send-fm(),
      sign: function(),
      unlockAccount: function()
    },
    timeout: {},
    poll: function(),
    reset: function(keepIsSyncing),
    send: function(data),
    sendAsync: function(data, callback),
    sendBatch: function(data, callback),
    setProvider: function(p),
    startPolling: function(data, pollId, callback, uninstall),
    stopPolling: function(pollId)
  },
  formatter: function(),
  get: function(callback),
  stopWatching: function(callback),
  watch: function(callback)
  }
```

How to let it show my console.log?